# Laptop won't wake up from sleep after undocking

Tags: multiple-monitors, suspend, power-management, thinkpad

My problem is quite strange I couldn't find a source of the issue so I will just try to explain problem manifestation and hopefully someone will have an idea how to solve it (or just how can I start tracking the issue).

I have Thinkpad t460p and docking station ThinkPad Ultra Dock. I am running Ubuntu 16.04, kernel 4.4.0 with i3wm. 
When I plug laptop to docking station everything works fine I can set monitors as I like (using xrandr) and also suspend and wake laptop from sleep (while docked). 
Problem: if I undock laptop, it is then impossible to wake it up from sleep. Pressing power button turns the laptop on, but screen is always blank and it doesn't react to any inputs. Only way around it (as far as I can see) is to force reboot the laptop. 
Interesting thing is that undocking laptop while it is not suspended works until it gets suspended and after it encounters same issue. If the laptop was undocked while suspended it will also encounter same issue.

**My question is**, how can I address this problem, where can I find more information about what could be wrong, logs or any other hints what could be a problem.

One more observation: If i don't setup external monitor with xrandr unplugging laptop while awake works, as I can later wake it up from sleep, but in case of undocking it while encounter same issue.

Thanks

Comment: Try this.  If not installed, install `pm-utils`.  Then run `sudo pm-suspend` to put the laptop to sleep while docked.  Do like you usually do and undock it, then try to open it.  Report back if that works for you.

Comment: Nope, same issue again. Just black screen after waking up and no reaction to any input.

Comment: Sounds like you will have to start looking into log files.  If you have another system to SSH into it, perhaps you can view the dmesg output from it.  Not sure if it will work, but you could also try `dmesg -w > ~/file.txt` and then repeat the issue.  After rebooting, read the file.txt to see what errors pop up.

Comment: Ok I did some dmesg logging into file but it turns out that it wasn't appended after booting. Chunk of dmesg is http://pastebin.com/SfNTbgy3 if you are willing to take look at it. I did two suspends one while docked just to have successful procedure saved and one when undocked to see where it breaks. First case was at 429 where wlan device is deauthenticated and after that cpu cores are shut down. After that i boot it up, undock it and suspend it again at 718 (wlan deauthenticates again but nothing after that is recorded). Im not sure if data is just not preserved on HDD or nothing happened?

Comment: Seems there are multiple bug reports on this already with displayport/hdmi/multiple monitors.  It was supposed to be fixed in kernel 4.4.0-24.43.  Can you confirm what exact kernel you're running with `uname -a`?

Comment: This is exact version: 4.4.0-66-generic #87-Ubuntu

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55550/discussion-between-milan-and-dorian).

Comment: Did this issue get resolved in chat? Same here.